# Listening to specific ip address

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, network-programming

I trying to listen to the ip address 10.100.102.3 , but VS 2013 throws an error:

> "The requested address is not valid in this context".

My ip address is 10.100.102.7.

Code :

```
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.100.102.3"), Port);

listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
listener.Listen(100);
Receiver = listener.Accept();
```

Comment: You define what IP address you're listening *on*, not what you're listening *to*. i.e. you need to provide a LocalEndPoint.

Comment: Thank to you very much .

Answer (score 2):

You cannot listen to a specific address people send *from*. The address you gave has to be an address that people can send *to*.